bash autocomplete custom script with possiblities from a text file
I have a shell script that I want to run that accepts one argument (it's actually a short hostname). All of the legal hostnames for that script are stored in a plain text file, one entry per line. I'd like to be able to type the name of my script, then have autocomplete work for the one argument.
For example, assume my script is on my path and is named run_remote.sh. All of the possible arguments to this script are stored in ~/data/remote_hosts.txt I want to type run_remote.sh and then have autocompletion fill candidates based on the contents of ~/data/remote_hosts.txt

I figured out a working solution:
_run_remote_completion() {
  local cur_word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  local hosts=$(cat ~/data/remote_hosts.txt)
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$hosts" -- "$cur_word"))
}
complete -F _run_remote_completion run_remote.sh


This needs explaining; is the last line how to use it? Why? Why not plain tab completion on the actual script? Place this in .bash_aliases? What more?

I've placed this in a file in ~/.config/bash_completion.d/
Note that _run_remote_completion has to be unique. Two examples are in https://github.com/egoforth/bash-autocomplete-from-file

I've added a copy on gitlab at https://gitlab.com/egoforth/bash-autocomplete-from-file
